# Add a class to a child element only of the same div using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to add/remove a class to an element (child of the same div is being clicked) for example, if the user press the #first element: The first element should now have 2 classes: .block .active. and the

should now look red, But every other should remain intact.  I've try the following (code below) nonetheless after I click on one block all of the blocks change their state and now all of them have both classes: .block .active.

Since I have a lot of blocks, If possible I don't want to use id selectors, just detect and apply the desired classes on the same parent div.

**css**

```
.block p{
 color: blue;
}
.block.active p{
 color: red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="block" id="first">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
<div class="block" id="second">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
<div class="block" id="third">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".block").click(function(){
    $("block").closest( "block" ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Instead of using `.block` & `closest` you can target the element being clicked with `this`.

In the below code, we are first removing the active class from all elements with class `block` and then applying the `active` class to the clicked element.

```js
$(".block").click(function(){
    $('.block').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass( "active" );
});
```

```css
.block p{
 color: blue;
}
.block.active p{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block" id="first">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
<div class="block" id="second">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
<div class="block" id="third">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
```

```js
$(".block").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
      $('.block').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.block p{
 color: blue;
}
.block.active p{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block" id="first">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
<div class="block" id="second">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
<div class="block" id="third">
   <p> Element in blue </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Zam, thanks for your clarification. If I remove the "removeClass" it won't be switched back if another div is clicked, right?

Comment: I've just did what you just share, nonetheless, I have one little problem: using toggle: If I press 1 .block it add the second class .active and If I press it again it disables it. But now If I press the same block (using removeClass) only removes the class If any other block element is clicked, but not from the same .block element, how can I change this?

Comment: @AlexandroGiles Added a new code snippet for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".block").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need I don't know how do I pass this.